# What is the effect of Binaural Beats on an Autistic brain?

Tags: consciousness, neurology, unconscious, autism, binaural-beats

I understand a fare bit about autism, and Binaural Beats.

Autism is the result of synaptic pathways becoming malformed during the fetal stage of pregnancy.

A Binaural Beat is a collection of two frequencies layered on top of each other to produce a third frequency which mimics a brain wave frequency.

I know they have done experiments on people to find the effectiveness of a Binaural Beat, under controlled conditions, to perform a triple blind study.
 However as an Autistic person I find myself wondering if any of the participants in that study had any form of Autism.

It seems to me that if the synaptic pathways in the brain of a fetus can become so malformed that they result in things like, Learning Difficulties and Pervasive Developmental Disorder Not Otherwise Specified with traits of Aspergers Syndrome, then how would the brain of an autistic person interpret a Binaural Beat in comparison to a Neurotypical person ?

Binaural Beats are essentially two similar frequencies, you play a Binaural Beat through headphones and the brain of a Neuro-Typical person interprets the two frequencies from both ears to create the actual Binaural Beat which only the brain can here.

Is this so for people with an Autistic Spectrum Disorder ?

Comment: The beat is called binaural (two ear).

Comment: I was wondering that myself !?
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6041407/

Comment: I can’t speak to the research, but I’m autistic and ADHD myself and find binaural beats helpful for focus and reducing sensory overload.

Answer (score 3):

The evidence in support of binaural beats as a therapeutic tool is sketchy: [Is there scientific evidence on the benefits of binaural beats?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8371/is-there-scientific-evidence-on-the-benefits-of-binaural-beats) Given our lack of understanding of if binaural beats can cause entrainment in the brain, never mind how they cause entrainment, it is not possibly to make conclusions about how the binaural beat would affect the autistic brain.